# Does Webflow.com produce usable code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have started using www.webflow.com to create the layout for an admin. It seems to do a great job of creating the flexbox layout, which is based on a PSD I created. It' also transpires the code down automatically so that I don't have to use Gulp. I plan to break it down into Ember components. Am I missing something here? I'm just getting back into development after many years of not developing and I am confident I can eventually do it myself, but Webflow seems like it could help save me some serious time since I already have high quality PSDs done for all views, which is my primary skill set, being UI design. Thanks allot for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer. Yes.**

Webflow produces valid code that will work in most browsers.

**Long answer. Be careful**

In my experience, webflow is great for simple pages. Landing pages, marketing material, etc. As with any HTML/CSS creation tool, it tends to be more verbose than if a front end developer were to make the site per hand. Not a problem if you're making a simple site, but it could lead to maintenance problems in the long run as your project grows.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Webflow for few showcase website. The code generated is pretty readable. If you already familiar with how Bootstrap structured, you can easily read CSS code generated by Webflow.

However, if you're using free plan of Webflow, you can't export your code in readable format.

**My opinion:** The creation of responsive websites is simpler

Comment: How so? I am new to Webflow, and I cannot figure it out. I have only been using breakpoints and padding, margins and spacing. 
But when I start moving it with the browser window or the built-in ruler, it goes everywhere. 
Yet, I know HTML5-JavaScript, React and Vue, so this is embarrassing to me, to say the least.